# Speed up annotation time in CoreNLP sentiment

Tags: java, command-line, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

In my dataset I have 100,000 text files, and I am trying to process them with CoreNLP. The desired result is 100,000 finished text file results, which has classified each sentence as having either a positive, negative or neutral sentiment. 
To get from one text file to annother text file, I use the CoreNLP jar file, which is used from the command line below.

```
 java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -fileList list.txt
```

It takes a very long time to do this, since I can't get the model to take every file in the filelist, but it will take the single path lines as input into the model.

I have furthermore tried to implement some of the other approaches in this link, but I can't get the result need from these.
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html#classpath

Is there a better and faster way to do this and speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
java -Xmx14g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment -parse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz -outputFormat text -filelist list.txt
```

It will use the faster shift-reduce parser.  This will run through each file in `list.txt` (1 file per line) and process it.

Comment: How does one do this via the CoreNLP API? Is that a configuration to the `parse` stage in the pipeline?

Comment: change parse.model